# Types of recursion in Sceme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm studying Scheme language (by myself). Recently I've encountered this question:
There are two functions which compute the same value (compose function f - n times).

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (= n 1)
        (f x)
        (f ((repeated f (- n 1)) x)))))

(define (repeated f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      f
      (lambda (x)
        (f ((repeated f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

As I understood these two are not recursive procedures but they return recursive procedures (lol). So what is the difference between these two? Is it possible that the first returns already computed procedure even before I give value to X? I'm so confused... Please help.

Comment: Both are just higher order functions (as they return a function). Conceptually there is no difference between what they try to represent

Comment: Thank you. However, Óscar López did point some minor difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact both procedures *are* recursive, each one is calling itself at some point during the execution. Also, both are returning a `lambda` at some point - meaning: they're procedures that return procedures.

The first procedure always returns a `lambda`, whereas the second procedure short-circuits and returns `f` when `n` equals `1`, but also returns a `lambda` for values of `n` greater than `1`. So they're not different, except for the way the base case (`n` equals `1`) is handled.

Comment: Thanks. the '(n equals 1)' explanation (second procedure) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that's so much simpler than mine, though mine is tail-recursive and works for (repeated fn 0) asuuming that running a function zero times on an argument is just that argument.

```
(define (repeated fn times)
 (let loop (
   (continuation (lambda (x) x))
   (count-down times))
  (if (not (> count-down 0))
      (lambda (x) (continuation x))
      (loop (lambda (x) (continuation (fn x))) (- count-down 1)))))
```

The difference between the two of yours is that the first returns a procedure right-away, and then calls itself as part of the procedure. The second returns a procedure only after it's fully calculated what that procedure will be.

Right so the first returns a recursive procedure, while the second used recursion to return a non-recursive procedure. Mine works more like the second, but can calculate repitition for very large numeric values while the two above will exceed the maximum recursion depth.

((repeated cdr 1000000) (iota 1000589))